# Windows Service, need advice on how to start

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I'm required to write a windows service( using C#.net) that reads a folder on a timely basis, and upon finding new files in the folder, import that new files to the current database. This is my first time writing a windows service. I really need some advices on how to start the writing process. thanks.

Comment: What language and framework are you comfortable working with?

Answer (score 1):

Read this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C) to understand how to create Windows Services using c#. Since you need to find the new files added to a folder i recommend using [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). Read this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18521/How-to-implement-a-simple-filewatcher-Windows-serv) to find how to use it.

There are some pitfalls in using FileSystemWatcher though. If you need more functionality than what is offered then read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58740/FileSystemWatcher-Pure-Chaos-Part-1-of-2)